# Export to CSV and view output on the screen

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to export data as a CSV and view the output on the screen at the same time?
The code below produces what I need, but if I use "tee" instead of Export-CSV, the data is stored the same way as I see on the screen (as I would expect)

Code:

```
Get-ChildItem  \\server\share-recurse -Filter "*.pst" | Where {$_.Length -gt 0} | 
Select-Object Directory, Name, Length, CreationTime, LastWriteTime | Export-Csv "C:\CSVs\mynew.csv"
```

Produces:

```
#TYPE Selected.System.IO.FileInfo
"Directory","Name","Length","CreationTime","LastAccessTime","LastWriteTime"
\\server\share\nightly.188\share\name","name.pst","271360","6/4/2009 2:42:21 PM","8/2/2011 12:00:32 AM","6/9/2011 8:58:50 AM"
```

If I use "tee", the Output on the screen and in the file look like this:

```
Directory     : \\server\share\nightly.188\share\name
Name          : name.pst
Length        : 271360
CreationTime  : 6/4/2009 2:42:21 PM
LastWriteTime : 6/9/2011 8:58:50 AM
```

Is there a way to format the screen and csv to look like a csv?

Comment: First, format for the screen. Then output to CSV. Two different commands. What's the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$foo | ConvertTo-Csv | Tee-Object -File output.csv | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Comment: This gave me the outputs that I needed.  Thank you!

Comment: This seemed to create for me a CSV that Excel opens everything in 1 column. No idea why.

Comment: @Nullldata Because your system locale doesn't specify `,` as the default field separator.